# use another entity information inside an entity FormType- Symfony3

Tags: forms, symfony

*Using PhpStorm.2016.3.2 with Symfony3 on Ubuntu16.04*

I have a FormType.php related to an entity called `Restaurant`.

Inside this entity, I have a foreign key called `city_id` connected with an entity called `city`.
So in my FormType I actually succeeded in calling my city entity with `EntityType::class` like that:

```
->add('city', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'                 => 'AppBundle:City',
            'choice_label'          => 'name',
        ))
```

This actually works and I have a `button` appearing on my page where I can select my cities from my database.

[image]

But I encountered a slight problem with that. What if my user wants to add a new city like `Amsterdam` as an example?

How can I do that in my `FormType.php` with my entity `city`?

Comment: check the CollectionType field https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: Thank you will check that :)

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to use an event listener/subscriber in your form type. You can look at [how to dynamically modify forms using form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).

How to proceed : When a user select a particular option in your select field called "city" then a listener/subscriber adds a text field to let the user write a city name.

So, in your form type, you can add an event subscriber like that :

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new CityFieldSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory(), 'city', $options['manager']);
```

Note that you need to pass an entity manager as an option of your form type.

Then create the subscriber (this is an example. I have not executed this code so there are probably errors) :

```
class CityFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $factory;
    protected $fieldName;
    protected $listenedFieldName;
    protected $repository;
    protected $optionId;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory, ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->factory              = $factory;
        $this->fieldName            = 'cityName'; // text field to add
        $this->listenedFieldName    = 'city'; // entity field to listen
        $this->repository           = $manager->getRepository('AppBundle:City');
        $this->optionId             = 0; // The value of the option in your select field
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA   => 'postSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT      => 'preSubmit'
        ];
    }

    private function addCityForm(FormInterface $form, City $city = null)
    {
        if (null !== $city) {
            if ($city->getId() === $this->optionId) {
                $form->add($this->fieldName, TextType::class, [
                    'label' => 'app.form.type.cityName.label',
                    'required' => true
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function postSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $city = $event->getForm()->get($this->listenedFieldName)->getData();

        if ($city) {
            $this->addCityForm($event->getForm(), $city);
        } else {
            $this->addCityForm($event->getForm());
        }
    }

    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();

        if (isset($data[$this->listenedFieldName]) && $data[$this->listenedFieldName] !== '') {
            $this->addCityForm($event->getForm(), $this->repository->find($data[$this->listenedFieldName]));
        }

        if (!isset($data[$this->listenedFieldName])) {
            $this->addCityForm($event->getForm());
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you need to write some javascript code to add the text field when necessary. See this example :

```
<script>
    var form = $('#form');
    var formUrl = '{{ url('app_front_form') }}';

    function replaceIfExistsOrRemove(selector, beforeSelectors, dom) {
        var $new = $(dom).find(selector).parent('.form-group');
        if ($new.length == 0) {
            $(selector).parent('.form-group').remove();
        } else {
            if ($(selector).length > 0) {
                $(selector).parent('.form-group').replaceWith($new);
            } else {
                for (i in beforeSelectors) {
                    if ($(beforeSelectors[i]).length > 0) {
                        $(beforeSelectors[i]).parent('.form-group').after($new);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    form.on('change', '#form_city', function() {
        $('#form_submit_button').prop('disabled', true);
        $.get(formUrl, $form.serialize(), function(html) {
            $('#form_submit_button').prop('disabled', false);
            replaceIfExistsOrRemove('#form_cityName', ['#form_city'], html);
        });
    });
</script>
```

After the form is submitted, if the form is valid, you save this new city and set it in your entity.

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thank you for your help @AlphonseD. :) (I liked your comment on stack)
Sorry to answer you just now but I didn't see it before. I used the folder `service` in order to make it work, without javascript, But your way seems to work, I need to check this out. Thanks !